# Adding custom layers to VGG-16

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, vgg-net

I am building an image classifier using Kerns, Tensorflow. I have a dataset of 4 different vegetables (Bell Pepper, Chile Pepper, New Mexico Green Chile, Tomato) each including five subfolders (damaged, dried, old, ripe, unripe) except the Tomato dried class because there are no images provided in the dataset.

```
Found 6180 files belonging to 19 classes.
Using 4944 files for training.
Found 6180 files belonging to 19 classes.
Using 1236 files for validation.
```

I've built my own model but I am not sure if it is correctly implemented because I am achieving a very high accuracy. I must admit the train dataset is heavily imbalanced at this point.

Following questions I am asking myself:

1. Is the implementation correct?
2. What do you recommend to change?

Here's my code for my model so far:

```
vgg = keras.applications.VGG16(
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape=(256, 256, 3),
    include_top=False,
)

for layer in vgg.layers:
  layer.trainable = False

def build_model():
    
    # add a Flatten or a GlobalAveragePooling layer
    x = layers.Flatten()(vgg.output)

    # add a Dense layer
    x = layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)

    # add a Dropout layer
    x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

    # add a Dense layer
    x = layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)

    # add a Dropout layer
    x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

    # add the final layer
    outputs = layers.Dense(class_amount)(x)
    
    # build the model
    model = keras.Model(inputs=vgg.input, outputs=outputs)

    # compile the model
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics='accuracy')
    # print the summary
    model.summary()

    return model

model = build_model()

# train the model
history = model.fit(train_ds,
                    epochs = EPOCHS, 
                    validation_data=val_ds,
                    verbose = 1)
```

I receive following results after training it for 100 epochs:

```
Epoch 95/100
155/155 [==============================] - 6s 36ms/step - loss: 0.2588 - accuracy: 0.9958 - val_loss: 2.0675 - val_accuracy: 0.9765
Epoch 96/100
155/155 [==============================] - 6s 36ms/step - loss: 0.3016 - accuracy: 0.9941 - val_loss: 2.1440 - val_accuracy: 0.9733
Epoch 97/100
155/155 [==============================] - 6s 36ms/step - loss: 0.2977 - accuracy: 0.9941 - val_loss: 2.1595 - val_accuracy: 0.9749
Epoch 98/100
155/155 [==============================] - 6s 36ms/step - loss: 0.2545 - accuracy: 0.9941 - val_loss: 2.3368 - val_accuracy: 0.9790
Epoch 99/100
155/155 [==============================] - 6s 36ms/step - loss: 0.1605 - accuracy: 0.9970 - val_loss: 1.8344 - val_accuracy: 0.9822
Epoch 100/100
155/155 [==============================] - 6s 36ms/step - loss: 0.2663 - accuracy: 0.9962 - val_loss: 2.8118 - val_accuracy: 0.9806
```

Comment: Is this a multilabel classification? If not you need CategoricalCrossEntropy. And also if it is imbalanced why you are using accuracy? Losses should tell you something is wrong.

Comment: @Frightera Just a quick note; binary cross entropy should be used for multiclass, multilabel classification, while categorical cross entropy is suitable for multiclass, single-label classification.

Comment: @NiklasLechler The title reads "Adding custom layers to VGG-16", but I don't see any custom layer in your code. Am I missing something?

Comment: @learner What you said is not correct, you are confusing multilabel and multiclass classification. You don't use BCE if your objective is multiclass classification.

Comment: @Frightera Thanks for your reply. My note was borrowed directly from "Deep Learning with Python" by François Chollet, Page 114 (Table 4.1).

Comment: @learner I see, *Binary Classification* would have been a better term as it is a special case of 2 class multi-class classification. Multiclass is generally used for tasks where number of classes > 2

Comment: @learner I thought I would add my custom layer in the build_model() function - don't do I  add a custom layer with that?

Comment: what do you guys recommend me to use then for multiclass classification?

Comment: @Nick Please feel free to see https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers for custom layer. You can also see many tutorials including https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification on classification. My understanding is that you have single label classification, for which the last layer typically has a softmax activation. Alternatively, you can use linear activation function, but apply the softmax to the logits for inference. Hope it helps.